# ngIf inside ngRepeat not working inside <table> when controller defined with string

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an ng-if inside an ng-repeat in a template, and the ng-if is not working, even if I change it to just

```
ng-if="false"
```

I can make it work by adding

```
ng-controller="TemplateController"
```

to a parent div, however when I do this, my controller cannot receive resolved arguments:

```
resolve: {
    myVar: function() {
        return "hello world";
    }
}

Unknown provider: myVarProvider <- myVar
```

if I remove the ng-controller, and add

```
controller: "TemplateController"
```

after my resolve:, then myVar is passed successfully, however ng-if no longer works

my HTML:

```
<table>
    <div ng-repeat=“row in rows"><tr>
        <span ng-if=“row.active==1">
            <td>{{row.data}}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>{{ row.date | date:"MM/dd/yyyy"}}</td>
            <td>
                <a href=“stuff”>click me</a>
            </td>
        </span>
        <span ng-if=“row.active > 1">
            <td>{{row.otherData}}</td>
            <td>{{row.str}}</td>
            <td>{{ row.date | date:"MM/dd/yyyy"}}</td>
            <td>
                <a href=“stuff”>click me instead</a>
            </td>
        </span></tr>
    </div>
</table>
```

right now, I get a whole bunch of blank cells, and *both* 'click me' links.

if I remove the  tags, it works, but it's not in a table

moreover, not only is the ng-if not working, but any variables I reference inside {{}} are being replaced with blanks (but they also work if  is removed)

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mh2UH/1/

Comment: Please show us more code and context..

Comment: use `ng-show/ng-hide` instead `ng-if`

Comment: @underscore they do not work either

Comment: we need more code then

Comment: Have you tried re-creating the issue on jsfiddle? Maybe you'll understand what is wrong when doing it, and if not then you can share the fiddle here to help us.

Comment: Please show the entire configuration of $routeProvider; are you specifying a controller there? Overall, you need to paste more code. We know *something* is wrong, but *that thing* is outside of the code you have included in your question.

Comment: after further investigation, I've found that it works correctly if I remove it from the table it is in (see html added above)

Comment: View the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48095079/3377733

Answer (score -2):

The golden rule to avoid this problem is

## Always have a dot in your angular bindings

```
ng-if="false"
```

Does not have a dot. Therefore the value false is being passed to the scope of the ng-if but can't be updated, since `false` is an immutable boolean value.

The correct way,

```
ng-if=status.enabled
```

Where status is an object.

Comment: You are right about always including a dot, but that doesn't have to do with his issue.