# How to use ng-if to display table rows

Tags: angularjs

I have one nested array to display table datas,Here I have written one condition to display the `tr`. if `ng-if="detail.college!='ddd'"` this condition does not  satisfies `tr` should not be displayed.
But table rows are not displaying properly.what I am doing wrong?

```js
var app= angular.module('myApp',[])
app.controller('myController',function($scope){
$scope.init = function(){
    $scope.data =[
   [
    {
    'name':'john',
    'college':'aaa',
    'department':'aaa',
    'age':20
    },
    {
    'name':'jss',
    'college':'bbb',
    'department':'bbb',
    'age':22
    }
  ],
  [
    {
    'name':'jack',
    'college':'ccc',
    'department':'ccc',
    'age':25
    },
    {
    'name':'bfff',
    'college':'ddd',
    'department':'ddd',
    'age':18
    }
 ]    
];
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController" ng-init="init()">
  <table ng-repeat="list in data">
  <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>{{list[0].name}}</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="detail in list" ng-if="detail.college!='ddd'">
      <td width="14%">{{leave.college}}</td>
      <td width="20%">{{leave.department}}</td>
      <td>{{leave.age}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Data structure shown is not valid. Beyond that what does *"condition not returning correct table data"* mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the incorrect data structure. I modified it. Please see it, I removed the object which was wrong.

**Controller:**

```
$scope.data =[
   [
    {
    'name':'john',
    'college':'aaa',
    'department':'aaa',
    'age':20
    },
    {
    'name':'jss',
    'college':'bbb',
    'department':'bbb',
    'age':22
    }
  ],
  [
    {
    'name':'jack',
    'college':'ccc',
    'department':'ccc',
    'age':25
    },
    {
    'name':'bfff',
    'college':'ddd',
    'department':'ddd',
    'age':18
    }
 ]    
];
```

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController" ng-init="init()">
  <table ng-repeat="list in data">
  <thead>
     <tr ng-repeat="detail in list" ng-if="detail.college!='ddd'">
        <th>{{detail.name}}</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="detail in list" ng-if="detail.college!='ddd'">
      <td width="14%">{{leave.college}}</td>
      <td width="20%">{{leave.department}}</td>
      <td>{{leave.age}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks.Is my `ng-if` condition correct?can you please check it?

Comment: Okay, what you want in that condition. I am not getting it properly from the question. Can you explain me here?

Comment: yea.Rows which has `college==ddd` should not be displayed in a table.

Comment: I have updated my answer, there was some also an issue in your HTML code.

Comment: Thanks. Surjeet one more doubt how can I use `toString()` here.which means `ng-if="detail.college!='ddd'"` this condition should satisfy for both uppercase and lower case.

Comment: You can do like this: ng-if="(detail.college).toString().toLowerCase() != ('ddd').toString().toLowerCase()"

Answer (score 0):

After some digging i came across a weird issue that ng-repeat doesn't work properly on tr so i have made some changes.

1. Used div instead of table for first ng-repeat.
2. Restructured the json since it wasn't valid.
3. Removed init function as we can directly access data.

```js
var app= angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myController',function($scope){

$scope.data =[
  [
    {
      "name": "john",
      "college": "aaa",
      "department": "aaa",
      "age": 20
    },
    {
      "name": "jss",
      "college": "bbb",
      "department": "bbb",
      "age": 22
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "name": "jack",
      "college": "ccc",
      "department": "ccc",
      "age": 25
    },
    {
      "name": "bfff",
      "college": "ddd",
      "department": "ddd",
      "age": 18
    }
  ]
];

});
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div ng-repeat="list in data track by $index">
    <span>
    <strong> {{list[0].name}}</strong>
    </span>
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="detail in list" ng-if="detail.college!='ddd'">
        <td width="14%">{{detail.college}}</td>
        <td width="20%">{{detail.department}}</td>
        <td>{{detail.age}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</div>
```